# No route matches RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have created a new put request in the one of the controllers with the following code:

```
#PUT /items/:item_id/offers/:id/accept
def accept
  @current_item = @current_user.items.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
  @offer = @current_item.offers.find_by_id(params[:id])

  @offer.update_attributes(:final_decision => 'Y')
  # @current_item.update_attribute(:traded,true)
  @offer.item.update_attribute(:traded,true)

  # Cancel other offers made for that item
  @current_item.offers.each do |rejected_offer|
    rejected_offer.destroy unless rejected_offer == @offer
  end

  # Cancel offers of that item to other items
  @current_item.offers_as_offered.each do |rejected_offer|
    rejected_offer.destroy unless rejected_offer == @offer
  end

end
```

Trying to test this with using:

```
it 'should accept' do

  put :accept, item_id: item.id, id: offer.id, access_token: user2.token

  expect(response.status).to eq(201)
end
```

I'm always getting:

```
Failure/Error: put :accept, item_id: item.id, id: offer.id, access_token: user2.token
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
  No route matches {:item_id=>"80794", :id=>"62087", :access_token=>"8b3deb96e92dbbee7b3aa25e488b5f40bc33c8ee078177370268520ef66f179a", :controller=>"items", :action=>"accept"}
```

The test is in `spec/controllers/offers_controller_spec.rb`. I also tried using

```
"/items/#{item.id}/offers/#{offer.id}/accept"
```

instead of `:accept` with no success.

My routes are:

```
resources :items do
  resources :offers, only: [:index, :create, :destroy, :update] do
    put :accept, on: :member
  end
end
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Added rake routes output.

```
accept_item_offer PUT    /items/:item_id/offers/:id/accept(.:format)  offers#accept
```

Comment: does the route show up as expected when you do a `rake routes`?

Comment: Yes it does. I updated the post with the route.

Comment: pay attention on error message `... :controller=>"items", :action=>"accept"` - it tries to find action `accept` in `Items` controller! Recheck that you describe `OffersController` in your spec.